# Create new variable (in new columns but not create new column) from rows with same ID in R

Tags: r, reshape

I want to change may Data Frame (left) to (right).
I used reshape package, however it will create new column not as what I want create

[image]

Thank you so much if someone can help me solve my issue!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please have a look at the posting guidelines, including [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mcve], then edit your question accordingly.  It's hard to help you without a clear problem statement or a reproducible example.  (And please don't post screenshots or images of code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you consider this solution as well.

Data generation

```
dt<-data.frame("id"=sample(3,5,replace = TRUE),value=sample(5))
m<-merge(dt, dt)
```

And then

```
IDs<-unique(m[,1])   

i<-1
res<-NULL
while(i<=length(IDs)){

   res<-rbind(res, c(IDs[i],m[m[,1]==IDs[i],2]))
   i<-i+1
}
res
```

You can use, either `rbind`, or `rbind.na`

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another variable first that is either `v1` or `v2` (for the example data given above).

We use `ave` and `seq_along` to create a run-length type id column, `'idx'`. This variable will from `1` to the total number of observations for every group of `'IDBILL'`. We use `paste0` to add the suffix `"v"`.

```
(DF <- transform(DF, 
                 idx = ave(IDPRODUCT,
                           IDBILL, # grouping variable
                           FUN = function(x) paste0("v", seq_along(x))
       )))
#  IDBILL IDPRODUCT idx
#1    111    ABC123  v1
#2    111    ABC124  v2
#3    112    BCH134  v1
#4    113    ABC123  v1
#5    113    GDF345  v2
```

Now use `dcast` from `reshape2` to spread the `'idx'` column and fill in the values of `'IDPRODUCT'`.

```
library(reshape2)
(dcast(DF, IDBILL ~ idx, value.var = 'IDPRODUCT'))
#  IDBILL     v1     v2
#1    111 ABC123 ABC124
#2    112 BCH134   <NA>
#3    113 ABC123 GDF345
```

---

Without additional packages you could use `reshape` instead of `dcast`.

```
reshape(DF, idvar = "IDBILL", timevar = "idx", direction = "wide")
```

---

If you prefer `data.table` you could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, idx := paste0("v", rleid(IDPRODUCT)), by = IDBILL]
dcast(DF, IDBILL ~ idx, value.var = 'IDPRODUCT')
```

---

To finally complete the unholy trinity - try `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
DF %>% 
  group_by(IDBILL) %>% 
  mutate(idx = paste0("v", row_number())) %>% 
  spread(idx, IDPRODUCT) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

**data**

```
DF <- structure(list(IDBILL = c(111, 111, 112, 113, 113), IDPRODUCT = c("ABC123", 
"ABC124", "BCH134", "ABC123", "GDF345")), .Names = c("IDBILL", 
"IDPRODUCT"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the use of `ave` here?